# I'm unable to select Adaptive payments on Business Setup(paypal)

Tags: php, paypal

I've submited several Applications in order to get it work with adaptive payments!
Even though I still get the error:

User is not allowed to perform this action 
Chained payment

I found this doc https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/merchant/paypal_digital_goods-adaptive_payments_getting_started.pdf
but as it's stated on page three I cannot set-up my business account to Adaptive. the only types are: 
Paypal on ebay
Mass pay
Website payments standard
Paypal invoicing
Express Checkout
Express Checkout for digital goods.

NO Adaptive Payments!!!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the way you're setting up primary vs. secondary users.  Are you setting yourself as the primary and sending money out to secondary receivers, or are you acting as the secondary receiver?

If it's the latter then you'll need to make sure the primary receiver has setup permissions with your app to be able to send out payments as necessary.  This can be done manually from within their PayPal account profile or you can build it into your app using the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#permissions).

There's more detail about this in the chained payments section of the [Adaptive Payments documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).